# How to see history of commands entered as superuser

Tags: command-line, history, su, command-history

Is there a way to see the commands that I entered in `su` mode? Similar to the ~/.bash_history? Where would this be located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually it is in .bash_history. But when you `su`, you switch user, so you have to check .bash_history as the user you `su`'d to. When you `su` again, and type `history`, it will give you only the history from that user.

Eg. you changed to root, so using `history` as root again, or checking the root-homefolder (default is /root) for .bash_history will give you all previous commands.

Answer (score 0):

In *Debian* you can define the variable **SULOG_FILE** in file */etc/login.defs* as the log file for *su* activity.

You can test the contents of you *login.defs*, also *man su* can tell you if supported.